# How to collect the pivot borders in K-Way Partitioning Algorithm?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have implemented the K-Way Partitioning Quick Sort which is based on the [Peter Taylor's solution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89663/an-algorithm-for-k-way-array-partitioning).

How can i fill the given `q` array in the partitioning to be the borders of each pivot (<pivot and ==pivot values):

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class KWayPartition {
private:
    void swap(T* a, T* b) { T temp = *a; *a = *b; *b = temp; }
    int partition(T* A, int low, int high, T* lp,int* q)
    {
        if (A[low] > A[high]){
            swap(&A[low], &A[high]);
        }
        int j = low + 1;
        int g = high - 1, k = low + 1;
        T p = A[low], qq = A[high];
        while (k <= g) {
            if (A[k] < p) {
                swap(&A[k], &A[j]);
                j++;
            }
            else if (A[k] >= qq) {
                while (A[g] > qq && k < g){
                    g--;
                }
                swap(&A[k], &A[g]);
                g--;
                if (A[k] < p) {
                    swap(&A[k], &A[j]);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        j--;
        g++;
        swap(&A[low], &A[j]);
        swap(&A[high], &A[g]);
        *lp = j;
        return g;
    }
    void insertionSort(T A[], T r) {
        T ki;
        int j=0;
        for (int i=1;i<r;i++) {
            ki = A[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && A[j] > ki) {
                A[j+1] = A[j];
                j--;
            }
            A[j+1] = ki;
        }
    }
    void KPartition (T* A, T* pivots,int *q, int p, int r, int sp, int sr) {
        if (r<=p) {
            return;
        }
        if (sp<sr) {
            insertionSort(A,r);
        }
        else {
            int mid = p+(r-p)/2;
            int idx = partition(A, p, r, &pivots[mid],q);
            KPartition(A, pivots,q,p, idx - 1,r,mid - 1);
            KPartition(A, pivots,q,idx + 1, r ,mid+1,sr);
        }
    }
public:
    virtual void Partition (T* A, T* pivots, int* q, int p, int r, int k) {
        KPartition(A, pivots,q, p,r+1, 0,0);
    }
};
```

note that the array of pivots is already given and i need to implement it without the use of std functions.

I think it should be similar to `sorted` in python(`sorted(l,key=lambda x:[x[y]for y in k]`) that's not doing it in-place.

The equivalent key function to the python version would be:

```
[](T* a, T* b) {
    for (auto i : pivots) if (a[i] != b[i]) return a[i] < b[i];
    return false;
}
```

please have a look at my [test cases](https://tio.run/##rRjbbtpI9Bl/xWmqRbYxTWzIS4yReKmEWq0qLbv7wPLgGJcMNsY3klYR/fXsOTO@2zRu1Eg1M@c25z5n6oTheOc4L@9Z4PinrQszdkzS2LUPc6mEOXaSuHFaBaXs4H54mEvSKWHBDgL74Cah7biQpFtTkt6Hsb072HAMHFeSHB8FwPJZCmP2aKfunTRgQQqPtn9ykTg83fvMQWCS2ilzgHDO8RSkblzFLmXnGCQpLIfAFJP2mRCxoe8P/iMN7o9HH46hG9vpMZ6XfDHbPaQK8L3ZIJv1I5tbPcX1pLN60r27TIeQQlqTqBu9PaJT3ZIkx2cIuZAtArVz038oViX8jChpeXdXi8mzNEgfWDKe88CCBexDFuKzoM3j1SLE34JIeeaLH2IlcSfg/pVoosjYTU9xALIQOhdooYFC0luiZj1FzV4XdSkr2mpZPfTqK2zWQ5jVV5jVQ9i7vsLedQhDnqpeLUmtrKhIMMsDVCL6mcRacl@QekFeKaxRCVLFQoFRitSWKK2RtVklJUtFAWR4qTXH1D2EPvZE7LK8S67mWbv89K/9/YsdpyxlxwAqvRPw7/HItpA82aG8UsHWAL/3aCusgOShlapt4j9a3OPiHheEMOHM2UnjMJdNIhYah/nHJ7F4QCdxqX6o4V6FSOGMz/zLRXwFebFGhg2W2mJNDBulRNMf128oiDQY5kRmQXQupeGZe1QSSWEEullD7BBBrDAGXQOvi2wFZHR@VBTxDT@upHl6YJgWskdls1Ogrqswx9tgsYdNXNUWT1iyr5qR/@1HozrwXNu5fuKW52AjiKKukzI1F@sdeRZNGQ7R5hmq3Kalv9143Fbl/JoBuy4DOkW95pm@3un0UFvX@s6rMpSofVXRXZWmlXM1XXIsz4y2H1SfsmhfArL63QkIlnpReyygiQir569jnMorzDaUt4K46qEVeKyeyXvrpgR8xS7Dr0Rm6SabxSYbjZoO9hjPZLapu41KhVE51MFZ6uwpuW4ob8h8TCKPdQUOkSN9w@XvNx3Z3EyGemQK7qqNZ6n8cjd9KjtY1mbwG7LHY5pQXwE1Ev0mFD@x@EmybVJzJyUi3o2tJBRB6uwqyJGEs7oYEYtq9BZa3NmUeME2GVM4oF0WhCM5HofKtWG2CNj2GxEU/RWtRoPQtqGwfI0SNlrUqJHSVZxB@CjSyBUoj1pfrNHRuOrHSWwj6pgxEONI15K2nedivuYxY3F6sn0Ru5@EDsSd0BU7r@rrC5ohS4zqwI12o@SldTZfuHNtFsj81qZdgH6cYMnwDTV@fUIz6RLUBW4C9wmW62BDM26uWgH2NoIN1cxguFkbKsGlQe1ynS3nKnx9CjO6Jk48KZLYDrYyPXvkP//@/FmhsVkalDWMzDcm/szAABU8XGI1S4NBFnJGpTJFDMOYGCQQXzgpzGZwtQzwJHT6Io7t73dXBHODLQ7EndIDIZk8NFgIsVwzBf4AmQ7wSLNCOiehUzS4Qvh5gCejqeN5V2QoojcaBGO6ZpV8@heHV7TZC232qA3auc@1KS4uxu8KYTe2X0QNGPXowUC8I0GO1uQk7E04dPK3XI0ZgX24KblLCeeqS/8LPrLgTS695Leq9Ei8XJNXBXsdgq@@kGnAWcvcECdFM2AoFTdoolqCLQ6GHE59tzwYVTu/tKdIUcPuN@fBDnboWVgN@aA4hHtQJCrRFTiyrZhgWzgi3lsOn2UvjqMf2aPbmEiL1lH2@y@NoXIlbNSLldHRM4YQ6fnCyBeTfDGtNpTabco02GOianDQwDc7aKgLl/B9fevVtz4V0qhyoR6aAGlwrVaa4tZObUhOzgOO93aK2AGHZFHVwY5x2guoONH961CLdCWnyRO8SYRuiAylIckALG@8xLs5DC2atOQaTaqJhm7MqeYXiKbYkuONNFCvpfrMLHszX2mOy8VMyNXqmE0pQtljZMG7cXv@QAFW9/DBB5euyUcgedvjD5r2sV0jZufc6fUa14WdRcSUC08DMfv2fRj86vFF9PlMV/rd6FDnLWYZr5nlj/Uuw/yfz4higLq@rtpgvDVRMi260ATnBIcLBAdB0J0xfter53DZsnIV6TSHl3SRUX8@RBN6q1b2U9wfGp2KRh/pWpXwSusev/gTP8ZWKf57Azt43lPrgLe2VjVvp7pFvAb/Tvh3apGYWys2BZloB2xCT2g2VTJmSidUcM0m9YagZkaq2WsoC3JGauaInDXDGA2MUWD0BqYaUwFmOk/@bGNUN5Nyc85@81IoFLCayv8W3esa/qpS1dJvONloO/lXzKyw97Vv2sBM2/ZNeeH0Mel3nc9Xtw3MbVuz21KztppinWkc6RbDsokMi2HRRBOL0d2I9WKxWz4RZPREfi39Dw).

It needs to satisfy this properties at the end:

```
    A[p .. r]
    pivots[0 .. (k-1)]  an array of k ordered values (in ascending order)
    q[0 .. (2k-1)]      output array of borders
    At the end:
        A[p .. q[0]-1] < pivots[0]
        A[q[0] .. q[1]-] = pivots[0]
        pivots[0] < A[q[1] .. q[2]-1] < pivots[1]
        A[q[2] .. q[3]-1] = pivots[1]
        ...
        pivots[i-1] < A[q[2i-1] .. q[2i]-1] < pivots[i] 0 < i < k-1
        A[q[2i] .. q[2i+1]-1] = pivots[i]       0 < i < k-1
        ...
        pivots[k-2] < A[q[2k-3] .. q[2k-2]-1] < pivots[k-1]
        A[q[2k-2] .. q[2k-1]-1] = pivots[k-1]
        A[q[2k-1] .. r] > pivots[k-1]
```

Comment: You mean how to modify your `qq` array in `int partition(T* A, int low, int high, T* lp,int* qq)`? Maybe typo in the `while` loop, because I see you are swapping elements of `A`. If nope, disregard this comment, I didn't closely follow the algorithm explanation.

Comment: @pptaszni
But yes i need to fill the `qq` array with the correct `A` elements that they are in the borders of each pivot.  It has to pass this [test case](https://paste.rs/ZCp)

Comment: Can you give an example that shows it not performing correctly, i.e. provide a [mcve]? BTW: There's quite a bit in your code that could be improved, consider submitting it to codereview.stackexchange.com. Make sure to first read their site guidelines though!

Comment: Not performing correctly: "Now i want to change the q array elements such that it satisfies the partitioning properties", its not passing the [test case](https://paste.rs/ZCp)

Comment: Can you please include the simple test case in the question, along with a main that calls this code? I was kind of expecting std::vector and some better parameter names.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I have its at the end, click on "Here is a reproducible example of it failing" link. and i have to use it like this because i can't change the testcase or convert the array into vector...